# Angular for loop $http wait until finish

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this factory

```
produccionApp.factory('eskuratudatuak', function ($http, $q){
    return {
        getNestedDataBetter: function (desde, hasta){
            return $q.all (
                $http.get('/planificacion/1/' + desde + '/' + hasta)
            )
            .then (function(results) {
                angular.forEach(results.data, function(eguna) {
                    console.log("xie!");
                        angular.forEach(eguna.linea1, function(turno) {
                                angular.forEach(turno.ordenes, function(orden) {
                                    var url = "http://someurl:5080/expertis/delaoferta?of="+ orden.ref;
                                    return $q.all($http.get(url))
                                    .then(function(datuak){
                                        console.log("not finish yet");
                                        for ( var k=0; k < datuak.length; k++ ) {
                                            if ( datuak[k].QPendiente < datuak[k].QNecesaria ) {
                                                orden.badutstock = 1;
                                            } else {
                                                orden.badutstock = 0;
                                            }

                                        }

                                    })

                                });
                        });
                });
                console.log("finish!");
                return results.data;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And the output is:

```
Here!
xie!
finish
XHR finished loading: GET ....
not finish yet
XHR finished loading: GET ....
not finish yet
XHR finished loading: GET ....
not finish yet
XHR finished loading: GET ....
not finish yet
```

But the correct out should be

```
Here!
xie!
XHR finished loading: GET ....
    not finish yet
XHR finished loading: GET ....
    not finish yet
XHR finished loading: GET ....
    not finish yet
XHR finished loading: GET ....
    not finish yet
finish
```

I´m calling to a web service and when it is completed I´m building my data variable with some foreach loops witch sometime call another webservice.

I need to complete all this calling before returnin the data....

any clue??

Comment: Take a look at this library, probably helps https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is you are managing a cascade of promises, so you would need to manage the fulfill of those promises to allow the process to continue, but in your case you only wait for the first promise, then you launch some other requests and never wait for them to callback.

There are several ways to accomplish what you are looking for, but someone already has written a library you can use and see inside its code to learn how to do it.

Take a look here https://github.com/caolan/async.